# Trying to lazy load and return a list inside a @transactional annotated method and getting a no session error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

this works, but when I try to remove the `courses.size` i get no session error.

```java
@Transactional
public List<Course> initiateCourses(Long id) {
    Instructor instructor = instructorRepository.findById(2L).get();
    List<Course> courses = instructor.getCourses();
    courses.size();
    return courses;
}
```

It works, but it feels like a hack.

also I found another way to load lazy collections.

```java
@Repository
public interface InstructorRepository extends CrudRepository<Instructor, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Instructor p LEFT JOIN FETCH p.courses WHERE p.id = ?1")
    Optional<Instructor> findByIdAndFetchCourseEagerly(Long id);
}
```

which one should I use performance wise? or is there a better way of fetching lazy initialized objects.

Comment: using second approach is the better way. The first one will cause N+1 query problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `@EntityGraph` to specify which parts of the object hierarchy should be fetched:

```
@Repository
public interface InstructorRepository extends CrudRepository<Instructor, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(type = EntityGraphType.FETCH, attributePaths = {"courses"})
    Optional<Instructor> findById(Long id);
}
```

See: [EntityGraph (Spring Data JPA)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/EntityGraph.html)

Comment: thanks, does caching also works in entitygraph?

Answer (score 0):

This proxy will not be initialized till you retrieve element from it or call `size()` method.
There are several ways to solve your problem without "magic":

1. Explicitly call `Hibernate.init()` and pass in it your collection-proxy before returning it from method.
2. Use entity graph as Peter Walser suggested